# Attach file to approval workflow email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, outlook, attachments, approval-process

There is a working approval workflow process using SharePoint 2010, Outlook 2010 and InfoPath 2010. When the task is reassigned to an individual the user needs to attach a document to the task assigned. The "Open this task" dialog box was created using InfoPath.

Infopath has a control to attach a file, however this approval workflow InfoPath template does not show that control as an option.

How would I be able to accomplish attaching a document to the workflow task?

Control Options in Approval Workflow

[image: Control Options in Approval Workflow]

Control Options in General Workflow

[image: Control Options in General Workflow]